# Edit Physical/External Android Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I am working on a product running over Android 5.1 and it has an attached external physical keyboard.

I have received the source code for this keyboard in order to add a ESC key option to a key is not being used. I have downloaded Android Studio and loaded the .apk file to the software but I have no clue where and how to add this ESC option to this specific key.

I have never worked on Android development so I would appreciate any help/support in order to locate this position and changing it.

Please see image below

[Android Studio screenshot loaded with the external keyboard project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4GK2.png)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands

You need to override

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_#:
            return super.onKeyUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ESC ,event);
        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

To get the key, breakpoint the switch and press the key, then you have the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_#`
Then override and return the escape key.

Comment: @josecaputo Great, you want to mark this as the answer so others will know the answer